# I want to make streaming job in Apache Flink to do Kafka -> Flink -> HIVE

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to make streaming job in Apache Flink to do Kafka -> Flink -> HIVE in Apache Flink(Scala).
Can anyone please give code sample as their official document is not very clear to understand.

This should be streaming process.

Comment: There's an example in SQL in the docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html#full-example.

Comment: I need to do scala code, this example is in the SQL query form. is it possible to do that in scala code? 
Currently, I am trying to write data directly into HDFS in ORC format but HIVE is not reading data written by Flink, not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For help getting started with the Table API, [Real Time Reporting with the Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/try-flink/table_api.html) is a tutorial you can follow. It's in Java, but the Scala API isn't much different.

[This](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html#full-example) is an example of using SQL to read from Kafka and write to Hive. To do the same from Scala you can wrap the SQL statements with `tableEnv.executeSql(...)`, as in

```
tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE Orders (`user` BIGINT, product STRING, amount INT) WITH (...)")
```

or

```
val tableResult1 = tEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO ...")
```

If you need to do multiple inserts, then you'll need to do it a bit differently, using a `StatementSet`. See the docs linked to below for details.

See [Run a CREATE statement](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/create.html#run-a-create-statement), [Run an INSERT statement](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/insert.html#run-an-insert-statement), [Apache Kafka SQL Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html), and [Writing to Hive](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/hive/hive_read_write.html#writing-to-hive).

If you get stuck, show us what you've tried and how it is failing.

Comment: Is it possible to directly write to file using File Streaming into ORC format and read it in HIVE table.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#orc-format

I have written the code to write in ORC format but Flink is making 103 KB files and writing correctly.

Comment: PS> I need to read data using specific offset from KAFKA and perform some operation and then write to HIVE so is it possible with what you suggested?

Comment: You can find my code here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826092/i-want-to-write-orc-file-using-flinks-streaming-file-sink-but-it-doesn-t-t-writ

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html#scan-startup-specific-offsets